# Update values inside dictionary of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains the information to make a POST request to site and fetch data.
Below is my dictionary

```
request_dict = {
    "scope_id": "user1",
    "tool_id": "appdynamics",
    "api_id": "get metrics names",
    "input_params": {"user": "abcd", "pwd": "1234", "acc_id": "ab12", "app_id": "TestApp", 
    "metric-path": "ars", 
    "time-range-type": "BEFORE_NOW", "duration-in-mins": 10},
    "output_filters": null
}
```

I have another dictionary which contains the updated value for some of the keys mentioned in the above dictionary.Below is the dictionary

```
new_metric_dict = {'tool_id': 'appdynamics', 'pwd': '5678', 'user': 'efgh', 'metric-path': 'ars', 'app_id': 'TestApp', 'acc_id': 'cd34'}
```

As you can see I got new values for user, pwd and acc_id.But I am unable to put these values into the POST request dictionary since they are inside `input_params`.

I tried doing something like this

```
for i in request_dict:
    if type(request_dict[i]) == dict:
        for j in request_dict:
            if j in new_metric_dict:
                request_dict[j] = new_metric_dict[j]
    if i in new_metric_dict:
        request_dict[i] = new_metric_dict[i]
```

But it doesn't work.What is an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way, which creates a new dictionary with the desired updates.

```
def update_dict(d, new):
    out = {}
    for m, val in d.items():
        if isinstance(d[m], dict):
            out[m] = {k: new.get(k, d[m][k]) for k, v in d[m].items()}
        else:
            out[m] = new.get(m, val)
    return out

new = update_dict(request_dict, new_metric_dict)

# {'api_id': 'get metrics names',
#  'input_params': {'acc_id': 'cd34',
#   'app_id': 'TestApp',
#   'duration-in-mins': 10,
#   'metric-path': 'ars',
#   'pwd': '5678',
#   'time-range-type': 'BEFORE_NOW',
#   'user': 'efgh'},
#  'output_filters': 'null',
#  'scope_id': 'user1',
#  'tool_id': 'appdynamics'}
```

Comment: this is what I needed!Thanks a lot!